# Problem with drawing

Tags: java, graphics, applet, drawing

For now the following code is supposed to draw a circle onMouseDragged over the black Canvas.
Unfortunately it doesn't (=
Do I miss something?

Thanks in advance...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.Graphics.*;



public class IdrawApplet extends Applet  {  


    int mosX;
    int mosY;
    Panel pGadgets;
    Canvas myCanvas;
    Label lRed;
    TextField tfRed;
    TextField tfGreen;
    TextField tfBlue;
    Label lGreen;
    Label lBlue;

    Graphics g;

  public void init() {

    g = getGraphics();
    lRed = new Label("Red-value: ");
    lBlue = new Label("Blue-value: ");
    lGreen = new Label("Green-value: ");
    tfRed = new TextField();
    tfRed.setText("255");
    tfGreen = new TextField();
    tfGreen.setText("255");
    tfBlue = new TextField();
    tfBlue.setText("255");

    pGadgets = new Panel();
    pGadgets.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 6, 5, 5));
    add(pGadgets);
    pGadgets.add(lRed);
    pGadgets.add(tfRed);
    pGadgets.add(lGreen);
    pGadgets.add(tfGreen);
    pGadgets.add(lBlue);
    pGadgets.add(tfBlue);

    myCanvas = new Canvas();
    myCanvas.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0));
    myCanvas.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);

    add(myCanvas);
    myCanvas.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            paint(g);

        }
    });


  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
      g.setColor(Color.green);
      g.fillOval(mosX, mosY, 30, 30);

      }





}
```

Comment: Thx for "edit". Code didn't show up as expected.

Comment: Doesn't look like `mosX` and `mosY` are set anywhere.

Comment: Changed to: public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   mosX = e.getX();
   mosY = e.getY();
   paint(g);
   
  }Still nothing...

Comment: Don't use `paint()` that's meant to be used internally. You should call `repaint()`. As it is now, you're calling `paint()` with a `null` since `g` never gets set.

Comment: Also, see my answer. You want to draw on the canvas, not on the component

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
{
   mosX = e.getX();
   mosY = e.getY();
   repaint(); //NOT paint(g);
}

//...
public void paint(Graphics g) 
{
    //draw on the canvas not on the component 
    //since the canvas gets drawn over it
    Graphics g2 = myCanvas.getGraphics();
    g2.setColor(Color.green);
    g2.fillOval(mosX, mosY, 30, 30);
}
```

If you have anything more complex, you should subclass `Canvas` and override it's `paint()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
{
    mosX = e.getX();
    mosY = e.getY();

    repaint();
}
```

The problem was that you were not updating your coordinates for the `mouseDragged` event. Also instead of calling `paint()` directly, you should call `repaint()`. Calling `repaint()` will ensure your `paint()` is called automatically.

EDIT:

To paint on Canvas object, override `paint()` of the `Canvas` object.

```
myCanvas = new Canvas()
{
    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillOval(mosX, mosY, 30, 30);
    }    
};
```

Now your mouseDragged method becomes :

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
{
    mosX = e.getX();
    mosY = e.getY();

    myCanvas.repaint();
}
```

Comment: Now it updates coordinates. But it still all happens behind myCanvas. Although I added my listener to the Canvas.

Comment: @bodycount PP, you may have to use `JLayeredPane` for that. Also you may need `g.fillOval((int)myCanvas.getLocation().getX()+ mosX, (int) myCanvas.getLocation().getY()+ mosY, 30, 30);`

Comment: @bodyCountPP You want to draw on the canvas, not on the component. See my updated answer.